# Starting New Project with Airplane Platform

Tags: ros, uav

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working on a personal project in which I want to write a ROS package that can send messages to control the flight of an airplane (ex. Venture, Flyin' King, etc.) with the works: ailerons, rudders, elevators, etc. Is it possible to develop a ROS package for this sort of platform?  Has any work been conducted on similar vehicles that could possibly be used as a guide? If not, what would be a good starting point for this type of project?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189036/starting-new-project-with-airplane-platform/) by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can definitely use ROS.
Consider how you plan on communicating with the plane. what device will be on the plane to control the motors?

One of the beautiful things about ros is how well it works with other projects.
You could integrate ardupilot with ros.

If you don't want to use a flight controller, you could also start with making a teleop plane in ros. Try the rosserial_arduino/Tutorials as a "warmup".
You can look at hector_quadrotor.

Good luck, and I look forward to seeing your developments.

---

Originally posted by [prosa100](https://answers.ros.org/users/19938/prosa100/) with karma: 56 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [musik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5129/musik/) on 2014-08-06**:
Thanks a lot. The device I was considering using to control the motors was a Piccolo autopilot. Hopefully it will work in a similar fashion to an ardupilot.